# PHP filter option won't accepts values from ajax call

Tags: php

I don't know what goes wrong with my script. I have a modal box which contains input fields. An ajax function submit these values to a PHP script. In my PHP script I have these two filters for the input values :

```
$userID= filter_input(INPUT_POST,"userid", FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);
$feedback = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"feedback", FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING);
```

But for some reason, these variables are null every time my ajax make a call. I changed these fields to this below:

```
$userID = $_POST['userid'];
$feedback = $_POST['feedback'];
```

And then it works I don't know what is not working with the above tow filters option

My ajax call just in case:

```
     function submitFeedback(){
       $.post(
     "../submitFeedback.php/",
     {
         userid: $("[name=changepasswordID]").val(),
         feedback: $("[name=submitfeedback]").val(),
     },
          function(data){
            $(".feedbackstatusdisplay").html(data);
      },
   );
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filters constant are wrong, it is `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` and you have typo in the second filter it is `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`

see documentation [Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Answer (score 1):

Filter inputs works properly in php 
$userID= filter_input(INPUT_POST,"userid", FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);//Your code
**need some changes**
$userID=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"userid",FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
//**FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT**

### this will removes illegal characters from input

$feedback = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"feedback", FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING);

$feedback = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"feedback", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//change it like **FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING**